# How to load a rendered Handlebars template into a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, handlebars.js, template-engine

I am trying to use the [Handlebars templating engine](http://handlebarsjs.com/) to dynamically build and add templates to my layout. I normally did this:

```
$('#pageTabContent').append('\
            <div class="tab-pane" id="'+ticketId+'">\
                And a whole lot more HTML here..
            </div>');
```

This works fine, but since I want to use Handlebars (to make things easier) I changed it to this:

```
$.get('/templates/tab_contents.html').then(function(src) {
    var renderedTemplate = Handlebars.compile(src)({ticketId: 99});
    alert(renderedTemplate);
    $('#pageTabContent').append(renderedTemplate);
});
```

The alert shows the html correctly rendered including the ticketId, but it simply refuses to be appended to the #pageTabContent. And here I'm kinda lost. I tried all sorts of variations, but I can't seem to get it to append to the #pageTabContent div.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here? All tips are welcome!

[EDIT]
The value it is trying to append and which I see in the alert is this:

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="99">
    This is the content from the separate file!
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$.get('/templates/tab_contents.html').then(function(src) {
    var renderedTemplate = Handlebars.compile(src)({ticketId: 99});
    alert(renderedTemplate);
    $('#pageTabContent').append(renderedTemplate.ToString());
});
```

renderedTemplate could be another object other than a string. may need to tostring it to get it to append correctly?

Comment: I of course also tried that, but unfortunately that also doesn't work. Since it is indeed the more logical try, I just edited my initial question so that it resembles that again. Would you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @kramer65 can you post the value that is shown in the alert so i can see what is trying to be appended? just add a console.log(renderedTemplate); so you can copy from the console window

Comment: Sure! I added it to my initial question. Its pretty simple I would say. Any ideas?

Comment: @kramer65, can you break on the append and inspect TYPE of rendered template. the $().append may be treating it as another object, not a string. may need to .toString() it?

Comment: I actually just thought the same thing a minute ago, so I just typeof'ed it, and it is indee d a string, so I guess thats not the problem (For the sake of my saneness I just tried the toString(), but to no avail..). Any other ideas.. :S

Comment: @kramer65 can you set up a jsbin or fiddle for this? i know its hard with the template but :|

Comment: I was already planning on writing an answer to you in the afternoon (which it is here now). Today I did a simple check whether (renderedTemplate === stringTemplate), and suddenly everthing worked. I seriously have no clue why it didn't before. It might be some kind of caching issue (which I thought I ruled out), or it was simply a very stupid mistake I made (but which I don't really know how I solved it). So although it is solved, I don't really know what the problem was. But I would like to thank you for your help and energy. People like you make the world a better place! :) Cheers!

Comment: @kramer65, thank you for the kind words. Happy to help when i can and enjoy a good problem solving.